# Trying to sign in Github using python but without the API

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I took it a challenge from myself to sign in github without using the API but with using requests module.I managed to get to this code and I get 200 status code but still there is a message which is "Incorrect username or password." even if the credentials is right!

any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def github_login():

s = requests.Session()
git = BeautifulSoup(s.get('https://github.com/login').text, 'html.parser')
auth_token = git.find("input", {"name": "authenticity_token"}).attrs['value']
commit = git.find("input", {"name": "commit"}).attrs['value']



data = {
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password',
    'commit' : commit,
    'authenticity_token' : auth_token
}

headers = {
    "Host": "www.github.com",
    "Origin": "https://www.github.com",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5",
}

login = s.post('https://github.com/session', data=data)

print (login.status_code)
print(login.text)


github_login()
```

Comment: why though? I don't really get it

Comment: why using this approach? Because I'm teaching myself  web scrapping and building bots and So here it come the Idea

Comment: I played around with this a bit and the only thing I found is that it didn't seem requests was passing cookies around like I would expect using the session.     The only other change I made was to include the utf8 field in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem and it was in the post request... "username" should be "login"

```
data = {
'login': 'username',
'password': 'password',
'commit' : commit,
'authenticity_token' : auth_token
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of forms like this have hidden input fields that prevent xss, replays, and other automated login attempts.  You may need to submit all of the extra form data included in hidden fields.

```
<input type="hidden">
```

It appears github uses cookies.  So what could be happening here is that you are getting a redirect reply that contains cookie info for you, but requests is following that redirect, but not setting the cookie.

Try turning off redirect following in your request

```
allow_redirects=False
```

Comment: I think I could know what exactly is sent in the post request using HTTP proxy like charles or something right?

Comment: You probably don't need to use a proxy, just parse out all of the other input elements on the form and see if there is anything else you are missing.  Also, this isn't going to work with users who have 2FA obviously.